# How to affect a SKNodes SKSpriteNode child?

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

```
-(SKNode*)node{

    SKNode *node = [SKNode node];

    SKSpriteNode *sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"sprite.png"];

    sprite.position = CGPointMake(100,100);
    sprite.name = @"sprite";

    [node addChild:sprite];

    return node;

}

-(void)affectSpriteInNode{

    SKNode *node;

    node = [self node];

    //node.sprite.position??????

    //Do something to sprite

}
```

How do I affect the sprite which is within node without having to affect node?

I still want them to be apart of node as if I wanted to change the node's position with all its sprites `node.position = CGPointMake(1,1);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out how to do it

```
SKNode *sprite = [SKNode childNodeWithName:@"sprite"]

sprite.position = CGPointMake(150,150);
```

simple.

Comment: if you need it often assign the sprite to an ivar